# Wrapping a node.js module using elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, elasticsearch

I need to use elasticsearch in my node.js project, whose API looks like the following:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
return new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace'
}));
```

However, my elasticsearch host is stored in zookeeper, so I first need to fetch it before returning the client. This is what I've come up with so far, which seems to work:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var zookeeper = require('node-zookeeper-client');

var zookeeperClient = zookeeper.createClient('localhost:2181');
zookeeperClient.connect();

var exportedClient = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  zookeeperClient.once('connected', () => {
    zookeeperClient.getChildren('/databases/elasticsearch', function (error, children, stats) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.stack);
        reject(error);;
      }
      resolve(elasticsearch.Client({
        host: children[0],
        log: 'trace'
      }));
    });
  });
});

exportedClient.get = function(args) {
  return exportedClient.then((client) => {
    return client.get(args);
  });
}

exports.client = exportedClient;
```

And then to use it:

```
var elasticClient = require('./myElasticClient').client;

var get = function(id) {
  return elasticClient.get({
    index: 'product',
    type: 'products',
    id: id
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response._source;
  });
}

exports.execute = get;
```

I'm very new to node, but there seems like there must be a better way to do this.